# Getting compile error while using <context:component-scan> annotation in spring xml

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to  annotation to auto-wire but getting compile error, I am not able to get the error message, there is only red cross at that line in spring XML. where I am doing wrong?

```
        spring.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/">

<!--commenting it out as we are using component annotation for this class-->

    <!--  <bean id="circle" class="org.devesh.learning.spring.Circle">
     </bean>
     -->  
       <bean id ="pointA"  class="org.devesh.learning.spring.Point">
      <property name="x" value="${pointA.pointX}"></property>
      <property name="y" value="${pointA.pointY}"></property> 
  </bean>


   <bean id = "center" class="org.devesh.learning.spring.Point"> 
      <property name="x" value="20"></property>
      <property name="y" value="0"></property> 
  </bean>


  <bean id = "pointC" class="org.devesh.learning.spring.Point">
      <qualifier value="circle related"></qualifier>
      <property name="x" value="-20"></property>
      <property name="y" value="0"></property> 
  </bean>

   <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="locations" value="pointconfig.properties"></property>  
 </bean>

 <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"></bean>

 <context:component-scan base-package="org.devesh.learning.spring"/>



</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it a possible typo?

as is:

```
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/
```

to be :

```
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
```